# What is the difference between this object initialization

Tags: c#, .net

```
           CustomerHistory objCustomerHistory = new CustomerHistory();

           objCustomerHistory.StatusId = customerHistoryModel.StatusId;
           objCustomerHistory.ActionId = customerHistoryModel.ActionId;
           objCustomerHistory.IsCurrent = customerHistoryModel.IsCurrent;

          //And

          CustomerHistory objCustomerHistory = new CustomerHistory
           {
              StatusId = customerHistoryModel.StatusId,
              ActionId = customerHistoryModel.ActionId,
              IsCurrent = customerHistoryModel.IsCurrent,
              HistoryData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCustomerModel),
              CreatedBy = customerHistoryModel.LoginUserId,
              CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
           };
```

What is the difference between this initialization.when i put the first initialization it give an error.how to fix it.

Comment: No differences, except that in second initialization you set more properties than in first one. What is the error message you got?

Comment: @Fabio error msg is: object initialization can be simplify

Comment: this is not an error, but warning, which you are free to ignore or disable.

Comment: That's not a warning. It's a suggestion for making your code neater.